# How to set table cells width fixed and make table to avail full available space

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have table with tds that looks like the following

[image: dashboard table columns]

As you can see there are four columns in a row with ids `salesComparisonCell, salesOverTimeCell, conversionsOverTimeCell and prospectsTableContainer`. Although `prospectsTableContainer` is a div but it is of `display: table-cell`. 
Now the problem is if one or two or three columns are not showing because of display none then each column is expand more than it is looking but the space is empty. Like the following

[image: column expand but with extra white space]

As you can see I just set the display of `salesOverTimeCell` to none. As a result of which `salesComparisonCell` becomes expanded but with extra blank space. I mean content size still the same but only extra blank area is showing with the content. I want instead of white space either the content expand also or if it is not possible because its a svg then the cell should remain to its original size.

I tried to set the width of the td in pixels but it didn't work. Although in percentage it worked but when I show the hidden td then it gets disturb.

Here is my try with width in pix[image: td with width in pixels not work]

You can see as the divs highlighted in green rectangle are of width 251px which is the content width. I also tried to set the td with as an inline property to 251px in red box but it didn't work. I also tried to change the width of the divs highlighted in green that may be this make content area to fit the available space but it didn't work either

With percentage it looks like

[image: width in percentage]

You can see `salesComparisonCell` now looks ok. Although other two tds now have problem. But if I add the `salesOverTimeCell` by just removing display none. Things get mess up.

[image: width in percentage problem]

So this is my first problem that how can I make the tds of graphs fixed or make the graph expand the whole area if one of the tds is removed ?

My second problem is the last td that is showing valus. Let say I hide two other tds. So now it looks like

[image: prospects table]

You can see there is also blank space. I set the `thead` and `tbody` properties to `display: block`. Now if I revert it back then contents expand but the problem is the scroll bar is gone and all table alignment. Here is the screen shot

[image: uncheck display block]

As you can see now no blank in prospects table but the problem is scroll bar is gone. Also table height also increases which disturb the whole page alignment.

So there is my second problem. Is there any way that after unchecking `display:block`. Scroll bar is not gone and table show with expanded contents like it is showing in above screen shot ?

How can I solve my problems ?